# Static dropdown list showing ID value instead of text on index view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu

How can i show the value i mean the text instead of the ID value of static dropdownlist in razor view here is the code

```
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Program_duration_Years)
</td>
```

and here it is in create view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.Program_duration_Years, new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem{ Text="Select Duration", Value = "0" },
    new SelectListItem{ Text="One year", Value = "1" },
    new SelectListItem{ Text="Two Year", Value = "2" },
     new SelectListItem{ Text="Three year", Value = "3" },
    new SelectListItem{ Text="Four Year", Value = "4" },
     new SelectListItem{ Text="Five year", Value = "5" },
 }, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "ddlduration" })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.program_type, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Comment: This code looks fine to me. What is the behavior you see, Value shown instead of Text?

Comment: on edit mode it is not showing the value selected which comes from database